# Printing n pairs of prime numbers, C++

Tags: c++

I need to write a program which is printing n pairs of prime numbers and the those pairs are :

p q

where p and q are prime numbers and q = p+2.

Input example :

n = 3

3 5 //
5 7 //
11 13 //

I'm pretty much nowhere still... So, someone?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int twins(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ???
     }
}

int main()

{
    std::cout<<twins(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given that you're expected to write multiple numbers, a design in which only a single number can be printed seems like a dead end right from the start.

Comment: And, where is your prime detection algorithm? I bet that you can find one, on the web, quite easily. And then, it's only a matter to adapting it, to detecting only pair primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the top-level simple pseudo-code for such a beast:

```
def printTwinPrimes(count):
    currNum = 3
    while count > 0:
        if isPrime(currNum) and isPrime(currNum + 2):
            print currnum, currnum + 2
            count = count - 1
        currNum = currNum + 2
```

It simply starts at `3` (since we know `2,4` is impossible as a twin-prime pair because `4` is composite). For each possibility, it checks whether it constitutes a twin-prime pair and prints it if so.

So all you need to do (other than translating that into *real* code) is to create `isPrime()`, for which there are countless examples on the net.

For completeness, here's a simple one, by no means the most efficient but adequate for beginners:

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return false
    root = 2
    while root * root <= num:
        if num % root == 0:
            return false
        root = root + 1
    return true
```

Though you *could* make that more efficient by using the fact that all primes other than two or three are of the form `6n±1, n >= 1`<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num < 2: return false
    if num == 2 or num == 3: return true
    if num % 2 == 0 or num % 3 == 0: return false
    if num % 6 is neither 1 nor 5: return false

    root = 5
    adder = 2                   # initial adder 2, 5 -> 7
    while root * root <= num:
        if num % root == 0:
            return false
        root = root + adder     # checks 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, ...
        adder = 6 - adder       # because alternate 2, 4 to give 6n±1
    return true
```

---

In fact, you can use this divisibility trick to see if an arbitraily large number stored as a string is likely to be a prime. You just have to check if the number below it or above it is divisible by six. If not, the number is definitely not a prime. If so, more (slower) checks will be needed to fully ascertain primality.

A number is divisible by six only if it is divisible by both two and three. It's easy to tell the former, even numbers end with an even digit.

But it's also reasonably easy to tell if it's divisible by *three* since, in that case, the sum of the individual digits will *also* be divisible by three. For example, lets' use `31415926535902718281828459`.

The sum of all those digits is `118`. How do we tell if *that's* a multiple of three? Why, using exactly the same trick recursively:

```
118: 1 + 1 + 8 = 10
 10: 1 + 0     = 1
```

Once you're down to a single digit, it'll be `0`, `3`, `6`, or `9` if the original number was a multiple of three. Any other digit means it wasn't (such as in this case).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you divide any non-negative number by six and the remainder is 0, 2 or 4, then it's even and therefore non-prime (2 is the exception case here):

```
6n + 0 = 2(3n + 0), an even number.
6n + 2 = 2(3n + 1), an even number.
6n + 4 = 2(3n + 2), an even number.
```

If the remainder is 3, then it is divisible by 3 and therefore non-prime (3 is the exception case here):

```
6n + 3 = 3(2n + 1), a multiple of three.
```

That leaves just the remainders 1 and 5, and those numbers are all of that form `6n±1`.

Comment: Thank you! :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most efficient but you can calculate all primes till n, store them in a vector then only print those which have a difference of 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void pr(int n, vector<int>& v)
{
    for (int i=2; i<n; i++) 
    {
        bool prime=true;
        for (int j=2; j*j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0) 
            {
                prime=false;
                break;    
            }
        }   
        if(prime) v.push_back(i);
    }
}
int main()
{
   vector<int> v;
   pr(50, v);
   for(int i = 0;i < v.size()-1; i++) {
       if(v[i+1]-v[i] == 2) {
           cout << v[i+1] << " " << v[i] << endl;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think is the efficient algo for you and easy to understand. You can change the value of k as per your constraints.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int n,p=2,savePrime=2,k=100000;

void printNPrime(int n)
{
    bool prime[k];
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));

   while(n>0)
   {
        if (prime[p] == true)
        {
            if(p-savePrime == 2)
            {
                cout<<savePrime<<" "<<p<<endl;
                n--;
            }
            // Update all multiples of p
            for (int i=p*2; i<=k; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
            savePrime=p;    
        }
      p++;  
   }

}   

int main() {
    cin>>n;
    printNPrime(n);
    return 0;
}
```