# My c program hangs in multiple different ways and why does it?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm creating a program that checks if an inputted number is a prime or not. It does this by dividing the prime by all the numbers between 2 and half the inputted number. It keeps hanging, I believe it hangs at the scan and also when I enter a static value for integer variable prime, it also hangs when I enter a nonnegative number greater than 1, though it shows my sanitation outputs like "its 0 and not prime". Can someone have a look? I'm quite new to C code and honestly don't see a problem with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int prime, limit, flag, i;
    float answer;
    printf("Please enter an integer for it to be checked: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &prime);
    if (prime<0)
    {
        printf("Prime numbers are always positive! In this case your number is not a prime.\n");
        return(1);
    }
    else if (prime==0)
    {
        printf("0 is not a prime number\n");
        return(1);
    }
    else if (prime==1)
    {
        printf("1 is not a prime number\n");
        return(1);
    }
    else
    {
        limit = prime/2;
        for (i=2; i=limit; ++i);
        {
            if (prime%i==0)
            {
                printf("This number is not prime");
                flag=1;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        if (flag==0)
        {
            printf("This number is prime");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (i=2; i=limit; ++i);` is obviously wrong. The middle expression should be a condition not an assignment.

Comment: If you only accept unsigned numbers, then why not take the input as unsigned?

Comment: I would suggest not to use unsigned integers unless some API forces you to, and even then typedef them; they are not a way to validate that a number is non-negative, quite the opposite; they'll force a negative to a high positive number, and you won't notice and get bugs. As for the question, I vote to close on account of multiple basic typos.

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `scan()`. You don't know if it works or not.

Comment: Voting to re-open. While a couple of the issues are typos, the scanf-with-newline issue is very much a subtle corner to the C standard library.

Answer (score 4):

For a start, get rid of the newline from:

```
scanf("%d\n", &prime);
```

This will continue scanning after your integer until it gets the first non-whitespace character, then pushthat character back into the input stream. The effect you'll see is, if you enter (for example) `42<enter>`, nothing will happen.

Secondly,

```
for (i=2; i=limit; ++i);
```

is an infinite loop unless limit is zero. The condition in the middle should use `==` rather than `=` and that means that `i = limit` will always be considered true for a non-zero `limit`.

Thirdly, the presence of that `;` at the end gives you an empty body for the loop, meaning the braced code following is just a scope-creating code block that won't execute per iteration (and not at all, given the loop itself is infinite).

Finally, you don't actually initialise `flag` to zero, meaning it will have some arbitrary value if the number is prime. That means detection of a prime will be suspect.

---

And, just as an aside, you don't need to go all the way up to half the number, you only need to go up to the square root (rounded up if not integral). That means your loop is better off as:

```
for (i = 2; i * i <= prime; ++i) ...
```

And you don't need to check every number in that range to see if it's a factor, you only need to check the primes. Now, if I knew a way to know that for sure, your question would be useless, and I would be very rich :-)

However, what I *do* know is that every prime other than `2` and `3` is of the form `6n ± 1, for n > 0`. Not every one of those is a prime but every prime is one of those.

Hence, you can use this fact (explained more fully [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208984/printing-n-pairs-of-prime-numbers-c/41209050#41209050) but basically doing `2` and `3` as a special case up front, then starting at 5 and alternately adding `2` and `4`) to optimise the loop (5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, ..., most of which are primes):

```
int isPrime = (candidate % 2 == 0) || (candidate % 3 == 0);
if (! isPrime) {
    int divisor = 5, delta = 2;
    while (divisor * divisor <= candidate) {
        if (candidate % divisor == 0) {
            isPrime = 1;
            break;
        }
        divisor += delta;
        delta = 6 - delta;
    }
}

if (isPrime) {
    doWhatYouNeedToDoForPrimes();
}
```

Comment: hey, Im actually laughing at how quick everyone was to spot the mistakes, comedic how good everyone is haha. Just a quick question, instead of the return command within the first if statement within the for loop, I want to put a break. Put when I put break it says it's not in a loop when its clearly in a for loop?

Comment: @jizzletothejsbaasi: no, you're not :-) The `;` at the end of the `for` line marks the end of the loop. As per my answer (though that update may may have come *after* your comment), the braced bit *under* the `for` statement is a standalone block, nothing to do with the loop.

Comment: @jizzletothejsbaasi the loop is empty as long as you don't remove the `; ` at the end of the line `for (i=2; i=limit; ++i);` as suggested in multiple comments and answers.

Comment: sorry @Jabberwocky , paxdiablo thanks much appreciated I shall dwell on this many days and nights

Answer (score 2):

This is an assignment, not a comparison: `i=limit`.

You also have an extra semicolon in the same line: `for (i=2; i=limit; ++i);`. That means a for loop with an empty body.

Comment: Just for clarification, where is the extra semicolon so I can delete it?

Comment: The last one at the end of the loop.